# c# - merge Point3DCollection

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have this code:

```
public Point3DCollection generatePoints()
{
     //generate some Point3D, add them to a Point3DCollection and return it.
     ....
}

//in the main function
Point3DCollection allPoints=new Point3DCollection();

while(...){
   //i need to merge the result from generatePoints() with allPoints, like this:
  allPoints.merge(this.generatePoints());
}
```

I want the merge() method is efficient, (i.e. not using for-loop or adding elements one-by-one). I know there is an addRange() for generic lists, but it's not available for Point3DCollections. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that every implementation of what you want will converge to loop at some point. Just implement this yourself. Compiler will take care of optimization.